# Should bytea used for binary operations in psql?

Tags: postgresql

Should bytea used for binary operations in psql?? I am trying to do binary operations & column with datatype bytea!!

Eg select * from orders where order_val & {bitMask} >0;
where order_val will be my binary strings stored in bytea, and bitMask is generated by the user query!.

Comment: If you want to use bitmask, then use [bit varying](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html)

Comment: are there any cons of using biginteger for the same?